# Does Saul Goodman know Hank Schrader is a DEA agent when he comes to meet Badger at APD interrogation room?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

I was watching the episode 'Better Call Saul' in Breaking Bad. It has the scene where Brandon Mayhew is sitting in the interrogation room of the APD and Saul Goodman comes in and the scene goes on. After talking with Badger, Saul goes near a water fountain and he sees an APD officer walking with Hank Schrader.

Yes, Saul knew that DEA are involved in Badger's case. But how did he exactly know that Hank was the DEA agent looking out for Badger? It could have been possible that the APD officer was also working on another case and the bald fat guy walking in civilian clothes might be some other officer from APD.

Saul Goodman walks up to Hank as if they know each other. The only thing that is sure, is that Hank knows Saul from the advertisements, but knows nothing personally.

My best assumptions would be that,

1. Saul hired his PI to investigate who in DEA will be handling the case. Bingo, Mike knows in and out of APD, couple of calls and Saul has his answers.
2. Since the blue meth case is high profile, APD will only be focusing on it, as well as DEA will be handling it. Thus, the person with APD is obviously/must be DEA agent. Saul deduced this.
3. I haven't seen 'Better Call Saul' series. So maybe, Saul has encountered Hank  previously, but Hank doesn't remember him.

Does anybody have better answers?

Comment: FWIW, I don't believe Hank appeared on season 1 of *BCS*.

Comment: Hank has not appeared in *Better Call Saul*, as of the end of season one. [Dean Norris](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0606487/?ref_=tt_cl_t4) has no credit for the show. That doesn't rule out Hank and Jimmy meeting before the events of *Breaking Bad*, so we'll have to wait and see.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, Hank appears in season 5. But Saul never meets him during the season.

Comment: @user28434 "*But Saul never meets him during the season.*" Saul meets Hank in S05E03 (aired Mar. 2, 2020).

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, Saul made an assumption and ran with it. If he was wrong (Hank is not involved), he can just apologize for the mistake.

But by being right (which he assumes he is - the odds are good given he's there for a Heisenberg-related drug bust and sees DEA), he comes across as all-knowing (or at least way ahead than they expect), which makes him seem very much on point for his client's legal defense.

Basically, it alerts the cops to make sure they do everything correct to the letter, because the attorney is paying attention (and seems to have background info).

Answer (score 2):

In *Better Call Saul* S05E03 "The Guy For This", it was “retconned” that Schrader met Jimmy when [Jimmy was representing Crazy-8.](https://www.indiewire.com/2020/03/dean-norris-hank-better-call-saul-right-time-1202215142/)

At the time, the implication is that Jimmy just knows all the local players.

Answer (score 1):

Saul, being like "Houdini" (Pinkman's words not mine), was able to save Emilio who was busted by Schrader in Breaking Bad Episode 1. Thus, it is conceivable that they had met then.

Come to think of it, I think he saved Emilio twice (from the scene where Jesse said "When the going gets though you don't want a criminal lawyer, you want a ***criminal*** lawyer")